# Add 30 seconds interval in a given datetime

Tags: php

Need some help.
I am using PHP.
So I have coordinates data.
Specifically `Longtitude` and `Latitude`.
So let's say I have 15 data of Long and Lat to be inserted on a table.
However, the api gives me only a single datetime because these coordinates are in array.
For example:

`[14.4364372;121.0125753, 14.4364375;121.0125755, 14.4364377;121.0125758, 14.436436;121.012574, 14.4364342;121.0125721, 14.4364326;121.0125704, 14.436433;121.0125707, 14.4364334;121.0125711, 14.4364338;121.0125716, 14.4364342;121.012572, 14.4364345;121.0125724, 14.4364348;121.0125728, 14.4364351;121.0125731, 14.4364353;121.0125733, 14.4364356;121.0125735]`

So first you will explode it to get rid of the delimeter ','
And loop it to count how many are data,then explode again the delimiter ';' to count the long and lat given.
But it only have a single datetime.
What i want here is to insert these data including datetime but with interval of 30 seconds per insert.
How can i do that?

Expected output would be like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_gps(ticket,datetime,long,lat) VALUES(0,09/16/2016 03:30:26 pm, 14.4364363,121.0125745) 

INSERT INTO table_gps(ticket,datetime,long,lat) VALUES(0,09/16/2016 03:30:56 pm, 14.4364364,121.0125746)
```

Here is my code:

```
$msg= 'YC GPS2~09/16/2016 13:29:46~-~[14.4364362;121.0125744, 14.4364363;121.0125745]';

if(strpos($msg,'YC GPS2')!==false){
//explode data
    $explode=explode('~',$msg);
    $ky=$explode[0];
    $datetime=$explode[1];
    $ticket=$explode[2];
    $coords=$explode[3];
    $coords=explode(',',$coords);

    for($i=0;$i<count($coords);$i++){
        $xpVal=$coords[$i];
    if($xpVal){

        $xp3=explode(';',$xpVal);

    $lng=$xp3[0];
    $lat=$xp3[1];
    $lng=str_replace('[','',$lng);
    $lat=str_replace(']','',$lat);
    $time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time() + 30);// where 30 is the seconds
    echo "INSERT INTO GPS2(ticket,datetime,long,lat)     VALUES(".$ticket.",".$time.",".$lng.",".$lat.") ";
    }
    }

}else{
    echo '0';
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is expecte outcome? how's it will look like? and what you have tried so for?

Comment: I have no idea what the actual question is? What do datetimes have to do with this? Where is the original datetime come from? How are they related to the long/lat pairs?

Answer (score 0):

In order to add how many seconds you want to particular date in PHP you can use the following.

```
$time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time() + 30);// where 30 is the seconds
```

The following is really easy way to add days, minutes, hours and seconds to a time using PHP. Using the date function to set the format of the date to be returned then using strtotime to add the increase or decrease of time then after a comma use another strtotime passing in the start date and time.

//set timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
```

//set an date and time to work with

```
$start = '2014-06-01 14:00:00';
```

//display the converted time

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('+1 hour +20 minutes',strtotime($start)));
```

Times can be entered in a readable way:

- +1 day = adds 1 day
- +1 hour = adds 1 hour
- +10 minutes = adds 10 minutes
- +10 seconds = adds 10 seconds

Comment: Already tried that.It adds a 30 seconds on time but that will be the same data to be inserted on the table.Already echo the insert statement 
Please take a look:




INSERT INTO GPS2(ticket,datetime,long,lat) VALUES(-,09/16/2016 03:49:36 pm,14.4364362,121.0125744) 
INSERT INTO GPS2(ticket,datetime,long,lat) VALUES(-,09/16/2016 03:49:36 pm, 14.4364363,121.0125745)

Comment: You show what is the code you have done for adding up the seconds to the date and where is your date coming from and what is the format of the date that you add to ??

Comment: Please take a look at my post,added my codes there.

Comment: @JohnMichaelRivera. Each time the for loop is repeated you have to increment the time by 30 seconds or what..

Comment: Need to add 30 seconds per insert